# How to make inner transaction rolled back, when the outer transaction failed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, transactions

I want to create a method thats called createTransaction that will commit the transaction if its success, but roll back all the transaction in some table if its failed. On the other side, I want to save the transaction log into db even if its failed or succeed.

I’ve tried this code, but when I try enter a customerId thats not saved in db, the transaction should be rolled back the transaction, product, and customer entity, but It still commit the transaction in product table. Can someone explain me whats going on and give me the solution for this?

```
public String createTransactionWithLog(TR_Transaction transaction) {
    String message = "";
    try {
        
        boolean successTransaction = createTransaction(transaction);
        if(successTransaction == true) {
            message = "Transaksi sukses";
        }else {
            message = "Transaksi gagal";
        }
        
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        Activity_Log log = new Activity_Log(LocalDateTime.now(), "DoTransaction", message);
        activityLogRepository.save(log);
    }
    
    return message;
    
}

@Transactional
public boolean createTransaction(TR_Transaction transaction) {
    long productId = transaction.getProductId();
    long customerId = transaction.getCustomer().getCustomerId();
    
    MS_Product product = productRepository.getOne(productId);
    MS_Customer customer = customerRepository.getOne(customerId);
    
    if(product == null || customer == null) {
        return false;
    }else {
        transaction.setCustomer(customer);
        
        int newProductStock = product.getProductStock() - transaction.getQuantity();
        product.setProductStock(newProductStock);
        
        transaction.setProductPrice(newProductStock);
        
        customer.getTransactions().add(transaction);
        
        TR_Transaction savedTransaction = transactionRepository.save(transaction);
        MS_Customer updatedCustomer = customerRepository.save(customer);
        MS_Product updatedProduct = productRepository.save(product);
        
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: I use h2 database. Is that matter?

Comment: Which line `createTransaction` gets committed on failure? Do you throw exception on failure?

Comment: The second createTransaction, how should I handle the exception

Comment: That is the behavior of standard nested transactions. Please try making the inner transaction nested. Since I'm not familiar with Java and h2 db, please try by yourself

Comment: How to make the inner transaction nested?